# Detect Input Content to Redirect to a Specific Page with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I have the following in my HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="code" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

What I want to do is to redirect the user to `page1.html` when s/he enters, let's say, <kbd>12345</kbd> and redirect him/her to `page2.html` when s/he enters <kbd>56789</kbd>. How may I do this with PHP? I'm okay with using JavaScript as well.

Let me rephrase that <sup><sub>(just in case)</sub></sup>.
I want to write <kbd>12345</kbd> in the input field, and after clicking the `Submit` button, to be redirected to `page1.html`. The same principle for <kbd>56789</kbd> and `page2.html`.

I found this old jQuery code of mine and changed it a bit. I'd be glad to hear your suggestions to polish it and achieve what I want.

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();

    var newVal = val.split('1234').join('HELLO');

    if (newVal !== val) {
        window.open("http://localhost:8000/page1.html");
    }
});
```

Additionally, is this right (for PHP)? <sub><sup>(didn't try it yet)</sup></sub>

```
if ($_POST['code'] == '1234'){
  header("Location: redirect_to_me.php");
}
```

<sup><sub>*Please bear with me as I am yet a fledgling in this field.*</sub></sup>

Thank you.

Comment: Just a side note: doing that in javascript is "dangerous", or not secure if you want to have a clear idea, because the user will always be able to inspect your javascript and get the target url.

Comment: Exactly. Perhaps unless I use `<script src="mycode.js"></script>` and disallow hotlinking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var pages = {
    "123456" : "page1.html",
    "56789" : "page2.html",
    "5252" : "page3.html"
}
$('input[type=submit]').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var val = $('input[name=code]').val();
var page = pages[val];

 window.location = page;

 });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be working perfectly. As I do not know JS/jQuery very well, I'd ask you how to add more values in the field when the statement is only with `if` and `else`?

Comment: Do you want to add more fields on the form?

Comment: No, just values. 123456 for page1.html, 56789 for page2.html and 5252 for page3.html, etc. :)

Comment: Updated the answer for your requirement

Comment: Accept the answer if you found this as useful

Answer (score 1):

Check your form submission (_POST or _GET) then redirect depending on the value of 'text'.  Just remember, you can only do a Location redirect when no output has been sent to the browser.. ..and always 'exit' after.

```
if(isset($_POST)){

    if($_POST['text'] == '12345'){

        header ("Location: page1.html");
        exit;

   } elseif($_POST['text'] == '6789'){

        header ("Location: page2.html");
        exit;

   } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this in PHP;

```
<form action="file.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="code" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And your `file.php` using a `switch` statement;

```
switch($_POST['code']):

    case '123456':
        header('Location: page1.html');
    break;

    case '56789':
        header('Location: page1.html');
    break;

    case '5252':
        header('Location: page3.html');
    break;

    default:
        header('Location: codenotfound.html');

endswitch;
```

Or a more elegant solution;

```
$page = 'codenotfound.html';

$pages = array(
    '123456' => 'page1.html',
    '56789' =>'page2.html',
    '5252' => 'page3.html'
);

if(isset($pages[$_POST['code']])):
    $page = $pages[$_POST['code']];
endif;

header('Location: ' . $page);
```